# What is the syntax that should be used for WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped?

Tags: wcf, webhttpbinding

I can't find any documentation on the syntax for a HttpWebRequest wrapped body.

Comment: Could you turn this into a question, and give more detail?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure if you are looking for:

- [A description of the enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb536115.aspx)
- [The effect it has](http://integralpath.blogs.com/thinkingoutloud/2007/05/wcf_web_smackdo.html)

Answer (score 0):

If your method looks like this:

```
string Echo(string echo)
{
   return echo;
}
```

Then the Wrapped request body looks like this in Json:

```
{"echo":"test"}
```

If you change the setting to "Bare" then it would look like this:

```
"test"
```